# Thor : How can I get my Thor task to display help when I have defined an argument?

Tags: ruby, thor

I'm converting a small project to use Thor, and being rather absent-minded I want to document the available tasks using built-in help.
But if I define a task with an argument the task-level help reverts to help for the class - which means no task description or details of the expected parameters are displayed.

I want to be be able to have a method I can call with an argument and not a parameter so it can be used like this

```
$ thor broke:foo hello
in a.thor broke:foo arg1=hello
```

I've boiled the problem down to the following thorfile which works as I want except the broken help output. I've stripped out any other parameters as they make no difference to the problem.
The first task ok:foo will display help normally, the second task broke:foo is rather less helpful :

```
class Ok < Thor
    desc "foo", "ok test2"
    def foo
        puts "in a.thor ok:foo\n"
    end
end
class Broke < Thor
    argument :arg1, :type=>:string, :desc => "arg1"
    desc "foo", "broke test1"
    def foo
        puts "in a.thor broke:foo arg1=#{self.arg1}\n"
    end
end
```

Requesting help for the ok:foo task method gives :

```
$ thor help ok:foo
    Usage:
      thor ok:foo

    ok test
```

Requesting help for the broke:foo task is rather less helpful :

```
$ thor help broke:foo
    Tasks:
      thor broke:foo ARG1          # broke test1
      thor broke:help ARG1 [TASK]  # Describe available tasks or one specific task
```

How can I define an argument and get the proper task help displayed ?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem in what you're trying to do, I think it's an actual bug in Thor.   I spent some time today poking around, trying to figure out what was going on, and I got to the point where I could figure out what was happening.   I filed a bug in Thor with a failing test and a description of your problem—I'll see if I can't try and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have small mistake in your thorfile.

You have **argument** instead of **method_option**.

Here correct version:

```
class Ok < Thor
    desc "foo", "ok test2"
    def foo
        puts "in a.thor ok:foo\n"
    end
end
class Broke < Thor
    method_option :arg1, :type=>:string, :desc => "arg1"
    desc "foo", "broke test1"
    def foo
        puts "in a.thor broke:foo arg1=#{self.arg1}\n"
    end
end
```

[Wiki about **method_option** on github.com](https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki/Method-Options)

Comment: Sorry but that is not a mistake - I want the method to require an argument and not a parameter - I've updated the question to clarify